# Can I define a "merge" alias for "git merge", etc.?

Tags: git, alias

I'm looking for a way to simplify and speed up my Git workflow. I've created the following aliases:

```
alias branch='git branch'
alias status='git status'
```

So, now, I can type `branch` into the Terminal and it executes `git branch`. However, what I would like is something like this:

- `checkout "branch-123"`, which would run `git checkout branch-123`;
- `merge "master"`, which would run `git merge master`;
- `new branch "new-branch"`, which would run `git checkout -b "new-branch"`;
- `push "branch-123"`, which would run `git push origin branch-123`.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it's a really bad idea. By getting around the convenient namespacing that the `git` command/prefix provides, you would open the door to clashes with other existing commands.

Comment: you can do it same way you did status and branch. what's the problem with creating aliases?.. @Jubobs it is obvious that you choose alias different from existing commands

Comment: @VaoTsun Regardless of the names you pick, I think it's a bad idea. Following this logic, why not expose all subcommands of all commands? What a mess that would be...

Comment: You can try to make an alias for git if it's too long for you (alias g='git'), and use git aliases for the rest of the commands, something like this https://github.com/Ujrep/configs/blob/master/.gitconfig

Comment: @StefanPerju so if I wanted to `git branch` I would write `git br` which this config

Comment: Exactly. Or if you define alias `g='git'`, you can just write `g br`.

Comment: @Donald Should I put the comment as an answer? Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can and the spirit is to simply not to go overboard and shadow other commands that you might need to use, e.g. the git plugin in `zsh` has several git aliases, among them:

```
alias gb='git branch'
alias gm='git merge'
```

so as long `gb` and `gm` aren't any command that you use, it's rather convenient

source https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh#L48

Notice that they are mostly if not all g-prefixed, e.g. when I did the same thing for my `vagrant` commands, I made them all v-prefixed, to keep some sense of namespacing while not typing too many characters

<sub>You can don't have to use `zsh` nor `oh-my-zsh` to use some ideas from that file</sub>